# Create Form in popup window and return result to Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created a popUp window on Actionbar Button click Event. In my popupWindow I have a Form. but When I give input in AutoCompleteTextView or select from Spinner my application crash.

Here is my popup window code

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout, null);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(GlobalSearch);
    IsSearchVisible = true;
```

Here GlobalSearch is a button in Action bar.
my search layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
android:layout_below="@id/banner">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_locality"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_locality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/icon_locality"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/locality"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Search by locality"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/for_need"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_locality"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/girl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_girl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/icon_girl"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_girl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Girls only"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/boy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_boy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/icon_boy"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_boy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Boys only"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_search"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/for_need"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/house_type"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:entries="@array/time_array"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FA5858"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Search"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is LogCat

```
03-20 15:28:57.706    2279-2279/com.nestaway.work.nestawayapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nestaway.work.nestawayapp, PID: 2279
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1d3f737a is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1058)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:962)
        at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:639)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1138)
        at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:683)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please Someone why is application crashing when I select from spinner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does LogCat tell ?

Comment: @Raptor just added logcat.

Comment: LogCat asks, "is your activity running?" What's the answer?

Comment: post your full code of ppopup window,and child decalarations(java code)